# missing event when using modules with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I had javascript code in a single JS file that was working fine (using XHR/AJAX).  When I split it up into separate modules in a requirejs application, I do not seem to get a handle on the event object & it shows up as undefined (testing in firefox 29.0.1).

**Calling module:**

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = new ajaxResponse().handleAjaxResponse(e);
```

**ajaxResponse**

```
    define(["require", './url/urlCommon'], function(require, urlCommon) {  
        'use strict';
        var ajaxResponse = function() { 
               var ajax = null;
              // e = event || window.event;
               this.handleAjaxResponse = function() { 
                   if (typeof event === 'undefined') {
                          var event = event || window.event;
                       }
                      console.log('e is now:' + typeof e);
```

I also do not have a handle on the event in the handleAjaxResponse method (error: undefined).  Any thoughts on what I need to do to troubleshoot/fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not giving nearly enough information to know what is going on here. You think RequireJS is the issue but you do not give your RequireJS configuration, show how you've split the relevant code into modules, how you've specified dependencies, etc. In particular what exactly is creating `window.event`?

Comment: @Louis - "var e = e || window.event;" is meant to normalize events for me across browsers.  It actually did not matter which event handler I run this code - it always comes out undefined for me in requirejs.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong - I need to figure out what.

Comment: I'm quite confident that requirejs is *not* the issue here (expect that `ajax` or `ajaxResponse` have the wrong scope), but that you're trying to use `window.event` in ajax. What is this supposed to do here?

Comment: @Bergi - I'm reasonably sure as well (as per my last comment - the issue is with my code). I just need to figure out what's wrong.  I am trying to assign the handler to handleAxaxResponse in ajaxResponse - it gets called but the event handling logic which was working previously is not working anymore when I ported code into the module.  I will continue troubleshooting (pretty sure its pilot error but need to confirm what it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my earlier note, it was caused by pilot error.  I modified my call to the event handler  using an anonymous function as the handler and passed the ajax/XHR object to the function (which was supposed to be the handler). The previous implementation appears to have resulted in losing the context for the ajax/XHR object.  I am sure there may be better solutions & would be glad to read about them.

**Calling module (New):**

```
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
              new ajaxResponse().handleAjaxResponse(ajax);
          }
      }
```

**Calling module (old):**

```
ajax.onreadystatechange = new ajaxResponse().handleAjaxResponse(); //handleAjaxResponse(ajax);
```